# Unable to determine why I am unable to update a record with php?

Tags: php, mysql

Using PDO I am attempting to update a particular database record via a form that is in part created by php. However, when I hit the submit button the page redirects to .

The Relevent Controller function:

```
public function updateRecord ($selectTable, $value) {
            include ('View/selectTable.php');
            $tableFields = $this->db->getTableFields ($selectTable); 
            $results = $this->db->getRecord($selectTable, $value);  
            echo $_POST['saveContactForm'];
            include '/View/updateRecord.php';   


        }
```

View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id= "saveContactForm">
    <?php for ($a = 1; $a < count ($tableFields); $a++):?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for=" <?php echo $tableFields [$a] ?>"><?php echo $tableFields [$a]  ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="<?php echo $tableFields[$a] ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $results[0][$tableFields[$a]] ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endfor ?>
    <input type ="submit" class ="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

I am not getting error or warnings. However, I did discover that regardless of where I put the echo $_POST['saveContactForm'] I am unable to get the post variables.

Comment: `echo $sql` does it look right?

Comment: Try to run sql in the database

Comment: @Dagon Doesn't print anything... which suggests the problem is the if statement (or something within the if statement) or the form isn't getting submitted correctly, but there might be an exception thrown somewhere.

Comment: so start basic debugging, echo echo echo.

Comment: Any string value?? Without quotes maybe

Comment: Maybe like that: `$sql .= $tableFields[$a] . " = '" . $formValues[$a-1]."'";`

Comment: do people really write this much code with out testing anything

Comment: @Dagon, No and for this exact reason.

Comment: @Dagon Isolated the problem  significantly, but still not 100% sure where the issue is.

Comment: in the form `method='post'` get is the default, as you have nothing it will default to get

Comment: @Dagon Well, that is embarrassing... Thanks for your help.

Comment: all good. you own me a be(e|a)r. :-)